# Junk characters getting inserted into DB Column from Java Application

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am having two different tables.I am fetching the value from a column of Table1 and then inserting it into a Column of Table2.No processing is done for that data in between, before inserting into secTable2.Both source and destination tables have same datatype - `varchar(50)`. Example data in Column: `CSC123`

When I query from destination table with SQL query (after insertion is done),Only 0 appears.When I export the results to excel,I could see some special characters before that 0 (Something like squares). This issue happens only for some cases and the actual data is missing.

Application : J2EE

Framework   : Hibernate

Database    : Oracle

Please suggest a solution

Thanks

Comment: Fetch the value a second time using Java and see if the special characters are there, and if so, what they are. Also, we likely can't do much without code.

Comment: This could be because of the difference in encoding type between your database and what is configured in hibernate.

Comment: Saposhiente : It happens in Live environment only,so couldn't simulate or replicate it locally.The special character looks like □□0 in excel sheet after exporting from the table.

Comment: Karthik :I have checked for the encoding type.It's same.But I have a doubt that how it happens only for some specific entries.Anything else should I check for ?

Comment: The problem is , there was a \n character which was getting inserted in DB.I was able to find it only by querying ASCII values from the DB Column.It's resolved now.Thanks everyone for the suggestions.